# ASP Identity Framework VerifyHashedPassword always returning Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

trying to have old hashed password checked with password history
as per ref from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40153621/178301
tried using `VerifyHashedPassword`

my sample code for testing why `VerifyHashedPassword` is failing:

```
var H1 = _signInManager.UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.Password);
var V1= _signInManager.UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(H1, appUser.PasswordHash);
var res = V1 == PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
Assert.IsTrue(res);
```

here `res` -> is always returning `false`

What is wrong with `VerifyHashedPassword` over here?

Comment: umm, is `VerifyHashedPassword` required you to pre-hash the provided password? which .net version is this (just to be sure)?

Comment: @BagusTesa you pin pointed the issue, I have feed hashed password whereas it requires plain text pws for comparision... I could mark it as correct if you post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Bagus, 2nd parameter of `VerifyHashedPassword` should be **plain text** not **hashed password**. So it should be like:

```
var V1= _signInManager.UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword( appUser.PasswordHash, model.Password);
```